# ImportError: No module named gi.repository Mac OS X

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, homebrew

I am installing **virt-manager0.10.0**  on Mac OS X

First I installed python,libvirt, gtk+3, pygtk, and other dependencies with **homebrew**

But when I run virt-manager I got this error

```
from gi.repository import GObject
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

When I run this import in python command line I get same error.but there is no error when I try    `import gtk`

I think the problem is the homebrew pygtk version doesn't use gtk+3 and uses gtk2 and as we can see here [gi.repository Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981137/gi-repository-windows)  only gtk+3 use that syntax.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `gi` module is in the `pygobject` package but if you install this package on OS/X, you won't get the `gi` module.
To really install `gi` on OS/X you need to install `pygobject3` module which may look like it's for Python3 but it's not, the `3` comes from GTK version.
So if you're on the OS/X, the simple `brew install pygobject3` will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, I am building rednotebook on os x. When I run the 'run' script, I get 'ERROR    pygobject could not be imported: "No module named 'gi'". Please install it (python3-gi).' I have executed 'brew install pygobject3', however I still get the same error. I have checked which modules are installed in '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/'. I can't se the gi module. Is the advice still current ? Any other idea on how to proceed ?

Comment: @stackQA did you find any solution to install rednotebook on mac?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo I did not find a solution to installing rednotebook on a Mac.

Comment: Looks like there's something up with brew's python & site-packages. I needed to use the PYTHONPATH env variable as described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394880/brew-installed-python3-9-modules-in-site-packages-not-found#comment120908755_68394880), and then `import gi` worked!

Answer (score 4):

pyGTK is for GTK 2 only. If you want the python bindings for GTK 3, you need to install pyGObject. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672426/518853

Answer (score -1):

Did you use the built Python or the one that home brew installed to `/opt/python/` ? issue `which python` in your term. Then in python issue `import sys; print sys.path`.

Comment: which  python : /usr/local/bin/python  

and sys.path :'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/site-packages/...

Comment: @MKT, is `/usr/local/bin/` your home brew path?  check this guide https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python. I suspect you installed libvirt and gtk using another python.

Comment: Yes thats brew path.
No I install gtk using brew python.

Comment: can you post the full list of commands you did as an update to your question?

Answer (score -1):

The python3 bindings for GTK3 can be installed with `brew install pygobject3 --with-python3` or  `brew reinstall pygobject3 --with-python3`

Comment: Running `brew reinstall pygobject3 --with-python3` produces a warning: 
`Warning: pygobject3: this formula has no --with-python3 option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: I tried with brew reinstall pygobject3 --with-python3 and got Error: invalid option: --with-python3