# Where is PyGtk binding API doc for Switch?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am running through the excellent [PyGtk tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/) and tracking it in what I thought was the most up-to-date [PyGtk API reference](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/index.html). The tutorial has a topic on the Switch widget but there seems to be no corresponding entry in the PyGtk reference. (There is an entry in the C-language GTK reference, but I was hoping to stay in Python land.)

This makes me wonder if I am somehow missing a more recent PyGtk API reference? The versions are a potential source of confusion, but it seems as if PyGtk is at version 2.x, the underlying Gtk is at 3.x and the tutorial uses Python v3.

Any thoughts on where I should look for PyGtk API documentation for the Switch widget?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the tutorial you referenced, there's a link for Gtk3 documentation (Python-specific reference): https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Switch.html#Gtk.Switch

Comment: In the words of a famous literary figure -- DOH!

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I needed. If you provide it as a response I will check the the checkmark.

I had actually looked at that, but it seemed so abstract I failed to recognize it was Python-specific. Your response encouraged me to look more closely.

Answer (score 1):

GtkSwitch appeared on Gtk+ 3.0 so probably you won't be able to use it from PyGtk (which uses Gtk+ 2.0), for Gtk+ 3.0 you should use PyGObject:

> PyGObject is a Python module that enables developers to access
>   GObject-based libraries such as GTK+ within Python. It exclusively
>   supports GTK+ version 3 or later. If you want to use GTK+ 2 in your
>   application, use PyGTK, instead.

- [Gnome's PyGObject](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject)
- [PyGObject in detail](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for catching my misstatement. The tutorial I referenced was, of course, based on PyGObject, not PyGTK.

Comment: PyGtk and PyGObject are distinct implementations. I think you were confused and GtkSwitch it's only available on PyGObject. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

PyGTK is for GTK+2. PyGObject is what you need for GTK+3.

Read [GObject Gtk, Gnome, Gtk+, Gl, Gtk2, Gtk3...I don't understand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667517/gobject-gtk-gnome-gtk-gl-gtk2-gtk3-i-dont-understand) to understand those differences.

For GtkSwitch, the official [GtkSwitch](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSwitch.html#gtk-switch-new) documentation clearly states it's available since GTK+3.0.

Answer (score 0):

As Answered by AndreLDM the api refrence is here 
lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/

For more info than covered in above link see the gnome developer manual for gtk+ in C - https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/

Gtk+ is made in C
so see (C!)  the gnome developer manual above explaining the C functions.
Also see the source code from gnome git - https://git.gnome.org//browse/

So first see the C documentation, code and then see the api documentation for pygobject (or your preferred language GbObject binding - c++, vala, haskell.gi and others)

### Cheers!

P.S - 
Gnome is an umbrella project to build awesome gnome desktop.
The Gnome Project contains libraries like the gtk+ toolkit to make widgets on desktop.
Gtk was first written to make the gimp image editing tool which is awesome too.